# Django - Using trees to build a comment system

Tags: python, django, tree

A few days back I was messing around with Django, trying to get a feel for how stuff works, when I decided to try and build a simple forum, one that resembled a forum that I frequented (but is now closed down). The idea was that each of the comments would be parent to any number of comments, like so:

```
 comment <--top
   comment <-- comment "A"
   comment <-- comment "B"
   comment <-- comment "C"
     comment <--C-1, reply to comment "C"
       comment <-- C-1-1, reply to comment "C-1"
         comment 
           comment 
             comment
         comment <-- C-1-1-1 reply to C-1-1
         comment 
         comment
           comment
             comment
     comment
     comment
       comment
         comment
           comment
             comment
             comment
             comment
```

The idea here is that replies to a comment would stuffed one level beneath it, and each comment, with the exception of the very first comment, has a parent. The thing is, although I get the idea behind implementing tree traversals, none of the books/articles I've read on the subject take Django into account (or the MVC pattern for that matter), so my question is how would I go about implementing this system in Django? (here's the model code i've got for reference :-/)

```
class Comment(models.Model): 
 Parent = models.OneToOneField('self', null=True)
 Children = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)

 Author = models.ForeignKey(User)
        Author_IP = models.IPAddressField()
 Created_On = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 Modified_On = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
 Body = models.TextField()
```

Comment: search in the archives you can find many answers. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=django+tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [django-threadedcomments](http://github.com/ericflo/django-threadedcomments). It's purpose is more fit to be used as comments on a blog than a full featured forum, but if it doesn't fit your case, you can at least look at the source code and learn a couple things from it.

As far as tree-based structures go, there are three projects I'm aware of for Django's ORM: [django-mptt](http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt/) (this one has the biggest "market share" with 3rd party django apps AFAIK), [django-treebeard](http://code.tabo.pe/django-treebeard/src/), and [easytree](http://bitbucket.org/fivethreeo/django-easytree/) (which is based on treebeard). Easytree comes with a nice admin interface, but the other two projects have at least patches in their issue trackers to add an admin interface (not sure if they integrated those patches already).

Answer (score 1):

I would only define the parent and give it a related name

```
class Comment(models.Model):
  parent=models.ForeignKey('self', related_name="children", null=True, blank=True)
  #other fields
```

Then you could get its children

```
comment=Comment.objects.get(id=1)
children=comment.children.all()

for child in children:
  morechildren=child.children.all()
```

Comment: So the "Children" field I have defined is no longer needed?